# Create Job Dynamically in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a job in `jenkins` with a configuration, then, with the `jenkins` API in `/cli`  i can `get-job` (API method) with an `xml` structure of my job and then i can `create-job` (API method) in `jenkins` with the followed xml.

```
?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
 <actions/>
  <description></description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties/>
<scm class="hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM" plugin="git@2.2.7">
<configVersion>2</configVersion>
<userRemoteConfigs>
  <hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
  <url>https://username:password@bitbucket.org/repoowner/project.git</url>
  <credentialsId>550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000</credentialsId>
  </hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
</userRemoteConfigs>
....
```

Even if i give this `url` tag "https://username:password@bitbucket.org/repoowner/project.git" jenkins needs authentication to work, so in `credentialsId` tag jenkins give an UUID.

I want to be able to create a job dynamically by an external application with a given URL in this format "https://username:password@bitbucket.org/repoowner/project.git".

How can it be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i solve the problem just creating an generic user in `bitbucket`, then the `UUID` its always the same and i can just copy and paste that UUID to the others `project.xml` files.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the credentialsId via the API and the credentials-store plugin.

e.g. for credentials in global Domain

${ your-jenkins-domain }/credential-store/domain/_/api/xml

```
<domainWrapper>
 <credentials>
  <_XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/>
 </credentials>
 <description></description>
 <displayName></displayName>
 <fullDisplayName></fullDisplayName>
 <fullName>credential-store/_</fullName>
 <global>true</global>
 <urlName>_</urlName>
</domainWrapper>
```

**But on some point it is a bit tricky:**
when accessing the xml api for global domain the id already has a '_' as prefix. When using other domains the prefix is missing (but in a job a prefix is added... couldn't figure out where the prefix can be found)

e.g. I stored github access data in a separated domain, the credentialsId tag was:

```
<XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/>
```

but used in a job id was:

```
0XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: @Seemann : you mean the credentials plugin? I can't find credentials-store plugin.

Comment: To get the list, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43318727/how-to-get-the-list-of-credentialsid-of-jenkins-by-rest-api/43319933#43319933