# How to get the list of credentialsId of Jenkins by rest api

Tags: rest, jenkins, credentials

I've already read "[Create Job Dynamically in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27692944/create-job-dynamically-in-jenkins/29047617#29047617)" QnA, and known how to get the information for a known credentialsId in xml format by "http://your_jenkins/credentials/store/system/domain/_/credential/503bcfce-4197-488d-be45-456623876087/api/xml" rest api.

But I want to get the total credentialsId list by rest api.

Please let me know how to do that if you know that.

Answer (score 4):

I've finally inferred an answer from the following post: [update Jenkins credentials by script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208763/update-jenkins-credentials-by-script)

Thank you for "Thomasleveil".

The procedure is as followings:

1) Install Scriptler plugin and restart Jenkins server.

2) Click Scriptler in side menu.

3) Click Add a new Script.

4) Fill the form.

[image]

The script is from "https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Printing+a+list+of+credentials+and+their+IDs", but run itself straightly and you can see the error messages: "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Jenkins for class: Script1 ... ".

This error has solved at "[Running Groovy command from Jenkins using Groovy script plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429050/running-groovy-command-from-jenkins-using-groovy-script-plugin)" post.

So your script is like:

`import jenkins.model.Jenkins
    def creds = 
        com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials( 
     com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardUsernameCredentials.class,
     Jenkins.instance,
     null,
     null
    );
    for (c in creds) {
        println(c.id + ": " + c.description)
    }`

5) Type "http://your_jenkins/scriptler/run/getCredentialsIdList.groovy" in your browser url bar.

You can see the list of total credentialsIds from your jenkins server.

Enjoy that ~~~